# Asus netbook trackpad suddenly stopped scrolling

Tags: netbook, scrolling, touchpad

I bought an Asus Eee netbook three days ago and, up until today, my two-finger scrolling was working just fine.  All of a sudden, dragging two fingers in a downward motion does not scroll anymore.  I checked the Pointing Devices control panel icon and no matter what I change in the properties, I can't get it to start again.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do other multi-touch features like pinch zoom work? Have you cleaned the touchpad?

Answer (score 1):

Start the Device Manager and look if there's a yellow icon somewhere. If there is one, try to look, if it is the driver you're searching for (Synaptics or smth like that) and install it.

Or it may be, that the driver is damaged, what means that you would have to search for the driver (in the device manager) and uninstall it, so that you can install it again (you probably will have to download it from the internet, just search for it)

For the Device Manager right click on Computer>Properties>Advanced System Settings>Hardware>Device Manager

On WinXP:
Right Click on computer >Properties>Hardware>Device Manager

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstalling the Synaptics driver - possibly installing the latest version. There has been an updated version available for mine on the asus site since I bought my eee.

If it is still not working then maybe warranty?